# White line on top whenever adjusting margin

Tags: html, css

Hey guys there seems to be a white line on top whenever i adjust the margin. 
The margin i adjusted is .box, when i adjusted it to 10px then a length of 10px white line would appear and whenever i adjusted it to 40px then a length of 40px white line appear.

The problem is I do not want the side bar to have the white line above as well. The side bar should have 100% height

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title> File Manager </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"> 
        <?php include "php/getrecord.php";?>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="sidemenu">
            <h2>Records</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a onclick="document.getElementById('Modaladdrec').style.display='block'">Add New Record</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="sectionbox">
            <?php while ($doc = $uid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):?>
                <div class="box">
                    <label>Height: <?php echo $doc["height"];?></label>
                    <br>
                    <label>Weight: <?php echo $doc["weight"];?></label>
                    <br>
                    <label>BMI: <?php echo $doc["bmi"];?></label>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile;?>
        </div>         
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
.box {
    width: 320px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    margin: 20px;
}

.sectionbox {
    margin-left: 200px;
}

body, html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

div, span, p, form, label{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}

#sidemenu {
    background: rgb(74, 10, 2);
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:192px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

#sidemenu h2 {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 52px;
    color: #ccc;
    font: 30px "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet Unicode MS", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#sidemenu h3 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 52px;
    color: #ccc;
    font: 20px "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet Unicode MS", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#sidemenu li {
    font: 67.5% "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet Unicode MS", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#sidemenu a {
    background: rgb(74, 10, 2);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(74, 10, 2);
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#sidemenu a:hover {
    background: rgb(111, 17, 4);
    color: #fff;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Picture below shows the white line cause my the margin of .box

[image]

Comment: Ok there is a margin when you set it, and what's the problem?

Comment: Ops sorry forgot the problem. I just edited it in. The problem is that i dont want the side bar to have space above. I wanted it to be 100% width.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this :

**Css** :

```
.sectionbox {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Well I still want the first box to have space. I dont want it sticking to the top. Sorry i just edited the problem in the question. I wanted the side bar to be 100% width. While the box still have white space above.

Comment: Ok, so just add a padding top to the container, setted a the margin you want... else, the margin will push all the block...

Comment: Ahh it works. Mind explaining why it works? i dont get the logic here

Comment: like why would margin push everything down?

Comment: Your section and sidemenu are on the same level, so your needs margin, so it will push anything to get a margin... hard to explain... but it works as this...

Answer (score 0):

I find often using 100% it makes it relative to the other sizes used for other class/id's and thus not giving correct measurements.

Have you tried using

Height:100vh;

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is to add a "float:left" to your sectionbox:

```css
.box {
    width: 320px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    margin: 20px;
}

.sectionbox {
    margin-left: 200px;
    float: left;
}

body, html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

div, span, p, form, label{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}

#sidemenu {
    background: rgb(74, 10, 2);
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:192px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

#sidemenu h2 {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 52px;
    color: #ccc;
    font: 30px "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet Unicode MS", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#sidemenu h3 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 52px;
    color: #ccc;
    font: 20px "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet Unicode MS", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#sidemenu li {
    font: 67.5% "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet Unicode MS", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#sidemenu a {
    background: rgb(74, 10, 2);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(74, 10, 2);
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#sidemenu a:hover {
    background: rgb(111, 17, 4);
    color: #fff;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title> File Manager </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="sidemenu">
            <h2>Records</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a onclick="document.getElementById('Modaladdrec').style.display='block'">Add New Record</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="sectionbox">
            
                <div class="box">
                    <label>Height: xxxx</label>
                    <br>
                    <label>Weight: yyyy</label>
                    <br>
                    <label>BMI: zzzz</label>
                </div>
        </div>         
    </body>
</html>
```

Click "Run code snippet" to try the solution.